# want to set value to an array key in react state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, setstate

In the below code I have a state inside in emplist array with some keys and by onchange() event i want to set the value to emplist array keys. How can i set that values please help me :).

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Registrations extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
      this.state = {
        EmployeeList:[
            { EmployeeId : '' },
            { EmployeeName :'' },
            { EmployeeSalary :'' },
            { EmployeeAddress : '' },
            { EmployeeDetails :false },
        ],
    };
}

handleChange = (e) =>{
    // some code actions//
}

  render(){
    var {EmployeeId,EmployeeName,EmployeeSalary,EmployeeAddress} = this.state;
    return(
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter EmployeeId" onChange={this.handleChange} 
                     value={EmployeeId} name='EmployeeId'/><br />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter EmployeeName" onChange={this.handleChange} 
                     value={EmployeeName} name='EmployeeName'/><br />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter EmployeeSalary" onChange= 
                     {this.handleChange} value={EmployeeSalary} name='EmployeeSalary'/><br />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter EmployeeAddress" onChange= 
                      {this.handleChange}  value={EmployeeAddress} name='EmployeeAddress'/><br />
                    <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you rephrase what you're looking for? It's unclear from your description so far. Also, please provide any code you have tried so far.

Comment: Why are you modelling `EmployeeList` as an array with objects with one single property each? Wouldn't it be more appropriate to have `EmployeeList` be an object with properties instead?

Comment: Your state's data structure doesn't make sense, it should just be a single object, not an array of 5 objects. Then to update one of those properties, the `onChange` just needs to pass the key to change and the value to change it to

Comment: @Tholle...I didn't understand your question. I am new  to react.

Comment: @Nick....in the EmployeeList array i want to set values by onChange() event. my code.....handleChange = (e) =>{ let x = [...this.state.EmployeeList ]; x[e.target.name] = e.target.value; this.setState({x}); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain more about what you want to do.

In your code above, you type in the data for each piece of data inside a single employee object, so you state should has this shape:

```
this.state = {
  Employee: {
    EmployeeId: '',
    EmployeeName: '',
    EmployeeSalary: '',
    EmployeeAddress: '',
    EmployeeDetails: false
  }
};

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      Employee: {...this.state.Employee, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
    })
  };

  render() {
    var {
      EmployeeId,
      EmployeeName,
      EmployeeSalary,
      EmployeeAddress,
    } = this.state.Employee; // change the destructuring as well
  }
```

Comment: ok thank you. now with onChange() event we have to set values to  employeeid, employeename etc.

Comment: can you give me onchange() event code pls.